# Delphi 2009: Is there a keyboard shortcut for searching the Structure panel?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

The question pretty much says it all.

I'd like to be able to search this like you can the Tool Palette with the Ctrl+Alt+P shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most panels have shortcuts:

```
Ctrl+Alt+P: Tool Palette
Ctrl+Alt+V: Event Log
Ctrl+Alt+B: Breakpoint List
Ctrl+Alt+T: Thread Status
Ctrl+Alt+S: Call Stack
Ctrl+Alt+W: Watch List
Ctrl+Alt+L: Local Variables
```

While debugging:

```
Ctrl+Alt+C: CPU
Ctrl+Alt+K: CPU Stack
Ctrl+Alt+E: Memory
Ctrl+Alt+M: Modules
```

But to the best of my knowledge, there is no shortcut to the Strucure panel.